# Having an <inputbox> that enters to a php variable

Tags: php, html, mysql

Ok so i have an inputbox and i am trying to make it so when you put lets say Title in that box it then adds it to a variable called $title and then i have $title in my title tags

```
<form id="curse-form" class="nm" action="title.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">              
    <div  id="loading" style="display: none" class='alert'>
        <a class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</a>
        Loading
    </div>
    <div id="response"></div>                      
    <div class="content_form">
        <input type="text" name="title" class="input-large" placeholder="Change title" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($title); ?>" />
        <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="icon-edit"></i>Change title</button>                           
    </div>                                      
</form>
```

No idea if i am doing it right with the form tags but in my title.php i just have php tags with $title=; but i am sure thats not how its done

I am not using a database for this but i am not sure if that is needed... as you can jsut store the title in a global variable? or is it better to use a database

Comment: so where is your php ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just submit the form?

```
$title = (isset($_POST['title']) && !empty($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : '');
```

Which is equivalent to

```
if(isset($_POST['title']) && !empty($_POST['title'])){
    $title = $_POST['title'];
}
else{
    $title = '';
}


$_SESSION['page_title'] = $title;
```

Then on your HTML

```
<title><?php echo $_SESSION['page_title'];?></title>
```

Comment: So how do you make $title go into the title tags.. as the title tags are loaded first..

Comment: @JordanCarr But does it answer your question at all?